# Increasing sequence of normal magic squares

Tags: recreational-mathematics, matrices

The questions below are motivated by pure curiosity. I heard of the first question from my former advisor. I have no idea how difficult they are, since I have no experience with magic squares.

By a normal magic square of order $n$ I mean a $n\times n$ magic square whose terms are all of the numbers $0,1,\ldots,n^2-1$.

> 1. Is it possible to construct an infinite sequence $M_n$ of normal magic squares such that $M_{n}$ is a block submatrix of $M_{n+1}$ lying in the centre of $M_{n+1}$ (i.e. to obtain $M_{n}$ we remove from $M_{n+1}$ the $k$ top rows, $k$ bottom rows, $k$ columns from the left and $k$ columns from the right)?
> 2. Can one construct a normal magic square of odd order (greater than $1$) with $0$ as the central element of the square?

Note that a positive answer to the second question gives a positive answer to the first one. Let $A=[a_{ij}]_{0\leq i,j\leq n}$ be a magic square as in question 2. For a number $c$ we shall use the notation $A+c=[a_{ij}+c]_{0\leq i,j\leq 2n}$ Then:
$$A'=\left[\begin{matrix}A+(n+1)^2a_{00} & \dots & A+(n+1)^2a_{0n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\ A+(n+1)^2a_{n0} & \dots & A+(n+1)^2a_{nn}\end{matrix}\right]$$
is a normal magic square with $A$ in the centre.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you are:
$$
  \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
 8& 15& 21&  2& 14\cr 
  \hline
20&  7& 13& 19&  1\cr 
  \hline
12& 24&  0&  6& 18\cr 
  \hline
 4& 11& 17& 23&  5\cr 
  \hline
16&  3&  9& 10& 22 \cr
  \hline
  \end{array}
$$

In fact, you may start with any weakly magic square (that is --- with no conditions on the diagonals); then you just need to permute rows and/or columns to satisfy the conditions on the diagonals.

I took a standard algorithm of constructing the magic squares of odd order; amazingly, I needed only to permute the columns. It seems that a similar method should work for higher orders as well.